# FileNotFoundError when extracting audio from recently saved video using FFMPEG"

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Scenario: I'm using [this tool](https://github.com/Michele0303/tiktok-live-recorder) to record tiktok live. I write another script to call the `main.py`tool because I want to add some additional options, for example, to extract the audio of the live video that is recorded

FFMPEG is used to extract the audio. First the video is saved (with FFMPEG) and after I want to extract the audio of that video (again with FFMPEG). The path where the video is recorded and saved is `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tiktok`

The problem is that I see the file and it is saved, but this error is generated as output: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

I can't figure out why it doesn't detect the last saved video file in general

I try with this

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def main():
    # Command to run main.py and record the video
    cmd = 'python main.py -user ryzebenny -output "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tiktok" -ffmpeg -duration 30 --auto-convert'
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)

    # Wait for the video file to appear in the folder
    wait_for_video("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tiktok")

    # Extract audio from recorded video
    video_filename = find_latest_file("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tiktok", ".mp4")
    if video_filename:
        video_path = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tiktok", video_filename)
        audio_filename = video_filename.replace(".mp4", ".mp3")
        audio_path = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tiktok", audio_filename)

        video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
        audio_clip = video_clip.audio
        audio_clip.write_audiofile(audio_path)
        audio_clip.close()
        video_clip.close()
        print(f"Audio extraction completed: {audio_filename}")
    else:
        print("No video files found.")

def wait_for_video(directory):
    max_wait_time = 60  # Maximum time to wait in seconds
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < max_wait_time:
        if find_latest_file(directory, ".mp4"):
            break
        time.sleep(1)

def find_latest_file(directory, extension):
    list_of_files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith(extension) and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f))]
    if list_of_files:
        return max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but i get this error

```
[*] 2023-08-03 15:57:09 - INFO - START RECORDING FOR 30 SECONDS
[*] 2023-08-03 15:57:09 - INFO - [PRESS 'q' TO STOP RECORDING]
[*] 2023-08-03 15:57:31 - INFO - FINISH: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tiktok\TK_ryzebenny_2023.08.03_15-57-09_flv.mp4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tiktok\TikTok-Live-Recorder\run_main.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tiktok\TikTok-Live-Recorder\run_main.py", line 12, in main
    wait_for_video("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tiktok")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tiktok\TikTok-Live-Recorder\run_main.py", line 34, in wait_for_video
    if find_latest_file(directory, ".mp4"):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tiktok\TikTok-Live-Recorder\run_main.py", line 41, in find_latest_file
    return max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen genericpath>", line 65, in getctime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'TK_ryzebenny_2023.08.03_15-57-09.mp4'
```

Instead, I expect that once I save the video (in .mp4) the audio of that video will be extracted afterwards